# deadlock on concurrent processes separated by transaction isolation level

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, transactions, deadlock, sql-server-agent

We have a workorder table. A server agent jobs grabs 100 entries from this table in a cursor and do some work. To parallelize this there are 10 server agent jobs, which call the following procedure (each with its own `@process_id`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_do_workorder @process_id INT
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @wo_id NCHAR(40),
        @wo_action NVARCHAR(100),
        @created_at DATETIME,
        @source_proc_name NVARCHAR(100),

    UPDATE procedure_ctrl SET [status]='running' WHERE [procedure]='sp_do_workorder_'+CAST(@process_id AS NVARCHAR(100)) AND [status]='idle'

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM procedure_ctrl WHERE [procedure]='sp_do_workorder_'+CAST(@process_id AS NVARCHAR(100)) AND [status]='running') BREAK

        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            UPDATE workorder SET hash=CAST(@process_id AS NVARCHAR(100))
            FROM workorder x
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT TOP 100 id FROM workorder WHERE hash='' AND workorder_step=0 ORDER BY created_at ASC
            ) y ON x.id=y.id
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

        DECLARE wo_cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT id,action,created_at,optin_source FROM workorder WHERE hash=CAST(@process_id AS NVARCHAR(100)) AND workorder_step=0 ORDER BY created_at ASC
        OPEN wo_cur
        FETCH NEXT FROM wo_cur INTO @wo_id,@wo_action,@created_at,@source_proc_name
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_basisprozess @wo_id,@wo_action,@created_at,@source_proc_name,@process_id
            FETCH NEXT FROM wo_cur INTO @wo_id,@wo_action,@created_at,@source_proc_name
        END
        CLOSE wo_cur
        DEALLOCATE wo_cur

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
    END

    UPDATE procedure_ctrl SET [status]='idle' WHERE [procedure]='sp_do_workorder_'+CAST(@process_id AS NVARCHAR(100)) AND [status]='running'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC dbo.sp_listerror
    DECLARE @error NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @error='[sp_do_workorder]_'+CAST(@process_id AS NVARCHAR(100))+': critical problem'
    RAISERROR(@error, 12, 1)    
END CATCH
```

We get a deadlock really often for most of these 10 agent jobs. Has anyone a hint why this is so? To prevent side effects we use serialize transaction isolation level, so only one agent job can grab one workorder entry. Without setting transaction isolation leven the deadlock are gone, but then it often occurs, that two (or more) agent jobs grab the same workorder entry.

Comment: See [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Comment: That sounds great! I'll give it a try (and give feedback later)

Comment: This seems to fit our need absolutely, really great. Please make an answer of you comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried to work out specifically why the deadlock would occur in your case but it seems as though you are effectively using a table as a queue in which case see [this linked article](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) for an approach that uses the `OUTPUT` clause and locking hints to maximise concurrency without deadlocks.